My copilot in vscode suddenly cannot be used
I was using copilot on a remote server. Today I found that it suddenly couldn't be used. However, my local vscode can use it smoothly.
After testing the network problem, the remote server can ping api.github.com.
The log detail:
2024-09-22 23:06:59.151 [error] [auth] auth: HttpTimeoutError: Request to <https://api.github.com/copilot_internal/v2/token> timed out after 120000ms
    at /home/xhl/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.232.0/lib/src/network/helix.ts:95:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at Hne.fetch (/home/xhl/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.232.0/lib/src/network/helix.ts:93:22)
    ... 5 lines matching cause stack trace ...
    at attemptAuthentication (/home/xhl/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.232.0/extension/src/auth.ts:58:9) {
  cause: AbortError: The operation was aborted.
      at fetch (/home/xhl/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.232.0/node_modules/@adobe/helix-fetch/src/fetch/index.js:96:13)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at cachingFetch (/home/xhl/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.232.0/node_modules/@adobe/helix-fetch/src/fetch/index.js:288:16)
      at Hne.fetch (/home/xhl/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.232.0/lib/src/network/helix.ts:93:22)
      at fetchCopilotToken (/home/xhl/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.232.0/lib/src/auth/copilotToken.ts:196:16)
      at authFromGitHubToken (/home/xhl/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.232.0/lib/src/auth/copilotToken.ts:129:22)
      at auth (/home/xhl/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.232.0/extension/src/auth.ts:40:25)
      at authShowWarnings (/home/xhl/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.232.0/extension/src/auth.ts:131:25)
      at yX.getCopilotToken (/home/xhl/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.232.0/extension/src/auth.ts:174:33)
      at attemptAuthentication (/home/xhl/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.232.0/extension/src/auth.ts:58:9) {
    type: 'aborted',
    _name: 'AbortError'
  }
}
2024-09-22 23:06:59.151 [error] [auth] Request to <https://api.github.com/copilot_internal/v2/token> timed out after 120000ms
2024-09-22 23:07:26.568 [error] [default] Error sending telemetry FetchError: connect ETIMEDOUT 140.82.112.21:443
    at fetch (/home/xhl/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.232.0/node_modules/@adobe/helix-fetch/src/fetch/index.js:99:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at cachingFetch (/home/xhl/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.232.0/node_modules/@adobe/helix-fetch/src/fetch/index.js:288:16)
    at Hne.fetch (/home/xhl/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.232.0/lib/src/network/helix.ts:93:22) {
  type: 'system',
  _name: 'FetchError',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  errno: -110,
  erroredSysCall: 'connect'
}

I hope to solve this problem

I encountered the same issue, and it was resolved by disabling the Intellicode extension. The solution was provided in this discussion
